# Can you convert these 2 IfElse Statements to 1

Tags: c#, if-statement

I try to shorten my if statements. I completed 1 but aren't able to see how to shorten the other 1 and clean it up. I Have shortened 1 as an example and I hope I can get some help :D.

I fixed this 1.

```
if (_clickDestination.Y < Position.Y && 
_clickDestination.Y != Position.Y && Position.X >= _clickWalkStairsX)
{
    Position.Y -= (int)StairSpeed;  // moves the person up on the stairs.
}
else if (_clickDestination.Y != Position.Y && Position.X >= _clickWalkStairsX)
{
    Position.Y += (int)StairSpeed; // moves the person down on the stairs
}
```

To this:

```
if (_clickDestination.Y != Position.Y && Position.X >= _clickWalkStairsX)
{
    if (_clickDestination.Y < Position.Y)
    {
        Position.Y -= (int)StairSpeed;  // moves the person up on the stairs.
    }
    else
    {
        Position.Y += (int)StairSpeed;  // moves the person down on the stairs
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to fix this 1 just like I did above.

```
else if (
    (_clickDestination.Y == Position.Y && 
    _clickDestination.X > Position.X) || 
    (_clickDestination.Y != Position.Y &&
    _clickWalkStairsX != Position.X)
) 
{
    Position.X += (int)Speed; // moves the person to the right
}
else if (_clickDestination.Y != Position.Y || 
    _clickDestination.X < Position.X)
{
    Position.X -= (int)Speed; // moves the person to the left
}
```

I hope someone can actually see how it needs to get fixed and would really appreciate it. ALl the if else will stand after each other.

Comment: First: ask yourself why you are shortening them. Does it make your code more readable? Can you understand it better? Second: I wouldn't shorten them, I would make them more readable by putting some/all of the expressions in methods so you can write "If (Inbounds(something))" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If changing at all, I would change it to this.
Where the the first condition deals with the Y comparison, and the second deals with the X comparison:

```
int speedChange = 0;

//...

else if (_clickDestination.Y == Position.Y)
   speedChange = _clickDestionation.X.CompareTo(Position.X) * (int)Speed;
else
{
   if (_clickWalkStairsX != Position.X)
      speedChange = (int)Speed;
   else if (_clickDestination.X < Position.X)
      speedChange = -(int)Speed;
}
```

Also, regarding the previous conditions, you could shorten it to:

```
if (_clickDestination.Y != Position.Y && Position.X >= _clickWalkStairsX{
    Position.Y += _clickDestination.Y.CompareTo(Position.Y) * (int)StairSpeed;
```